# How to save git pull options in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I select the "Pull..." action I have to every time choose same options again and again. How to set it up to prefill those options automatically? Or even just remember last ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, there is no option to save the choice in Pull dialog.

Please see and vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249119